# Never executed while loop slows down Rccp-function

Tags: c++, r, performance, rcpp

While trying to speed up my Rcpp-code I found some strange behavior I can't explain.

Consider the functions

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int TestRandC(int n) {

    Rcpp::NumericVector vec(1000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        vec[i] = (double)i/1000;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        double testvalue = 1.1;
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
            while(testvalue < vec[j]){
                testvalue += R::runif(0,1);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

and

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int TestRandC2(int n) {

    Rcpp::NumericVector vec(1000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        vec[i] = (double)i/1000;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        double testvalue = 1.1;
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
            while(testvalue < vec[j]){
                //testvalue += R::runif(0,1);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The only difference between the two functions is that the first line in the while loop is commented out. As the while loop is never executed (all values in vec are <1, and the testvalue is >1) I would expect the performance of the two functions to be identical. This is not the case however; running TestRandC(1e7) on my computer takes about 26 seconds, and running TestRandC2(1e7) takes about 11 seconds. Both function return 0, as you'd expect.

Further, removing the vector vec and replacing

```
while(testvalue < vec[j])
```

with

```
while(testvalue < (double)j/1000)
```

makes both functions perform equally slow (90 seconds on my computer).

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Can we make TestRandC run as fast as TestRandC2? (or faster... ?)

PS In my script the while loop will of course be executed, but only sporadically; giving testvalue an initial value of R::runif(0,1) seems like a good approximation.

Comment: I guess the compiler optimizes this for case 2 because only one variable can change, probably also helps the cpu's branch prediction and it can preload instructions more successfully. You could always take a look at the outcoming assembly. Should give you a hint about the possible overhead a single line can produce.